# How to replace NAs with the average of the nearest two values

Tags: r, replace, na

I have this data:

```
data <- structure(list(A = c(10L, 25L, NA, 17L, 8L, 3L), B = c(2L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 2L), C = c(NA, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I want to replace NAs at each column with the average of the nearest two available values at that column. For the result should be like below:

```
data <- structure(list(A = c(10L, 25L, 21L, 17L, 8L, 3L), B = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), C = c(4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `na.approx`

```
library(zoo)
data[] <- lapply(data,  function(x) na.locf0(na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE)))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  mutate_all(na.approx, na.rm = FALSE) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = 'updown')
#  A B C
#1 10 2 4
#2 25 2 4
#3 21 2 6
#4 17 2 4
#5  8 2 3
#6  3 2 3
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(A = c(10L, 25L, NA, 17L, 8L, 3L), 
   B = c(2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L), 
   C = c(NA, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I am getting -7 instead of 4 at C and 8 instead of 3 at the same column?

Comment: @mustafa I used only your dataset

Comment: A B  C
[1,] 10.00000 2 -7
[2,] 25.00000 2  4
[3,] 24.92828 2  6
[4,] 17.00000 2  4
[5,]  8.00000 2  3
[6,]  3.00000 2  8

Comment: @mustafa can you check now.  Sorry, there was a mixup

Comment: Do you think if the columns format changed to something that is date or time, the code should be applicable?

Comment: @mustafa if it is date or time class, the mean doesn't make  sense to me

Comment: The date and time columns are perfect and have no missing data in it. I do not want to change anything there. I have a problem with only three numeric variables.

Comment: then  just inddex only the colunmns needed to applky

Comment: @mustafa  can you try `data[1:3] <- lapply(data[1:3],  function(x) na.locf0(na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE)))` here 1:3 is the column index.  you can change it accrodingly

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `approx` with option `rule=2`

```
data[] <- Map(function(x) approx(seq_along(x)[!is.na(x)],
                                 na.omit(x),
                                 seq_along(x),
                                 rule = 2)$y, 
              data)
```

such that

```
> data
   A B C
1 10 2 4
2 25 2 4
3 21 2 6
4 17 2 4
5  8 2 3
6  3 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to apply the code to a bigger data that has date and time columns but it does not work.